# Deserialize JSON list

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to deserialize JSON list using Newtonsoft.Json and C#. This is my code:

```
List<Zone> zones = new List<Zone>();
string string = "[
      "{\"znId\":19,\"znCode\":\"ZONE_TS_10\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Zone Test 10 \",\"znPriority\":\"2\"}," +
      "{\"znId\":15,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST06\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 6\",\"znPriority\":\"3\"}," +
      "{\"znId\":20,\"znCode\":\"TS_ZONE_11\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"TS Zone 11\",\"znPriority\":\"3\"}," +
      "{\"znId\":21,\"znCode\":\"11_TS_ZONE\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"11 TS Zone\",\"znPriority\":\"4\"}," +
      "{\"znId\":16,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST07\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 7\",\"znPriority\":\"4\"}," +
      "{\"znId\":17,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST08\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 8\",\"znPriority\":\"5\"}," +
      "{\"znId\":22,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST12\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 12\",\"znPriority\":\"5\"}
]";

zones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Zone>>(string);
```

This is my object:

```
public class Zone {

    private int znId { get; set; }
    private String znCode { get; set; }
    private String znFiltre { get; set; }
    private String znDescription { get; set; }
    private String znPriority { get; set; } 
}
```

The `zones` list show 7 entreies. One for each zones of the string. But all the atributes of the elements are empty. What I'm doing wron?

Comment: Try making the properties public. Why are they private?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make your properties **public** and then correct your json. There is extra quotation mark (**"**) at start. Here is a correct version:

```
            List<Zone> zones = new List<Zone>();
            string @string = "[{\"znId\":19,\"znCode\":\"ZONE_TS_10\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Zone Test 10 \",\"znPriority\":\"2\"}," +
                "{\"znId\":15,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST06\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 6\",\"znPriority\":\"3\"}," +
                "{\"znId\":20,\"znCode\":\"TS_ZONE_11\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"TS Zone 11\",\"znPriority\":\"3\"}," +
                "{\"znId\":21,\"znCode\":\"11_TS_ZONE\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"11 TS Zone\",\"znPriority\":\"4\"}," +
                "{\"znId\":16,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST07\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 7\",\"znPriority\":\"4\"}," +
                "{\"znId\":17,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST08\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 8\",\"znPriority\":\"5\"}," +
                "{\"znId\":22,\"znCode\":\"PK_ZONE_TEST12\",\"znFiltre\":\"(select EMP_I_ID from V_ZON_SITE)\",\"znDescription\":\"Test 12\",\"znPriority\":\"5\"}]";

            zones = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Zone>>(@string);
```

---

```
    public class Zone {

        public int znId { get; set; }
        public String znCode { get; set; }
        public String znFiltre { get; set; }
        public String znDescription { get; set; }
        public String znPriority { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Make your properties public**, so that can be accessed outside of the class(NewtonSoft in this case)

```
public class Zone 
{
    public int znId { get; set; }
    public String znCode { get; set; }
    public String znFiltre { get; set; }
    public String znDescription { get; set; }
    public String znPriority { get; set; } 
}
```